# Dependencyproperty of type observablecollection throw exception

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, observablecollection, dependency-properties

I'm making a user-control which is called "FileSelector" based on listbox. The list box is filled with an observablecollection "FileDisplay" which contains file names selected from a dialog.

```
<ListBox x:Name="FileListBox" Template="{DynamicResource BaseListBoxControlStyle}" Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource BaseListBoxItemStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.FileDisplay, ElementName=F_Selector, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Button x:Name="ListDelete" Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ListDelete}" Style="{DynamicResource BaseButtonStyle}" Margin="4,0,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="X" Click="FileDelete_Click"/>
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="ListCheck" Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ListCheck}" Style="{DynamicResource BaseToggleButtonStyle}" Margin="0,0,4,0" Checked="File_Checked"  Unchecked="File_Unchecked" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource PathToFileName}}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

When a toggle button contained in the item is checked, I want to add the content of the item to a dependencyproperty of type observablecollection.

```
private void File_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ToggleButton btn = (ToggleButton)sender;
    int index = FileListBox.Items.IndexOf(btn.DataContext);
    FileChecked[index] = true;
    FileSelected.Add(FileDisplay[index]);
}
```

The dependencyproperty :

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FileSelectedProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("FileSelected", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(FileSelector));
    [Bindable(true)]
    public ObservableCollection<string> FileSelected
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)this.GetValue(FileSelectedProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(FileSelectedProperty, value); }
    }
```

Also, FileChecked is an observablecollection to keep track of which element is checked or not for later use.

Everything compiled fine but when I check one of the togglebutton this error is thrown :

```
Access violation at address 00007FFA2981CC85. Read of address 0000000000000000.
```

It is worth noting that if I changed the DependencyProperty FileSelected to a simple observablecollection, there is no problem, but I don't want to do that as I could not bind it later on.

Any idea why ? thank you

EDIT----
After some more testing with visualstudio debugger, I found that whenever I click on a togglebutton, the dependencyproperty named "FileSelected" is null, while it should be added "FileDisplay[index]" even if I replace the latest by any kind of string...

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused. You say this:

> It is worth noting that if I changed the DependencyProperty FileSelected to a simple observablecollection, there is no problem, but I don't want to do that as I could not bind it later on.

But in your sample, `FileSelected` IS an ObservableCollection. What data type was `FileSelected` originally intended to be?

> After some more testing with visualstudio debugger, I found that whenever I click on a togglebutton, the dependencyproperty named "FileSelected" is null, while it should be added "FileDisplay[index]" even if I replace the latest by any kind of string...

There's no way of telling why `FileSelected` is null without knowing its true data type. Is there only one file selected at a time or multiple?

If `FileSelected` is *supposed* to be an OC, it's probably null because you haven't a) initialized it anywhere, or b) you didn't initialize it properly.

Can you post a sample of your initialization?